# Open link in new tab selenium c#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a program to run videos listed on my site for testing purpose and here what I need is to run videos in different tabs of the same browser window.

I have hundred video urls in the List `videoLinks = getVideoUrls();`
and now what I need is to execute these videos 5 at a time.

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.withoutabox.com" + videoLink);
```

If I go the above way then for all videos I will have to create a new ChromeDriver object. I want to use single chrome browser object.

I have tried this

```
IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");
```

it only adds a new tab but not open a link there.
Please let me know how should I go around it. I have googled but couldn't find my solution so thought to ask for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void SwitchToTab(object pageId)
{
    webDriver.SwitchTo().Window(pageId.ToString());
}
```

You can use CurrentWindowHandle to find current tab.

```
webDriver.CurrentWindowHandle;
```

For your scenario I'm using that code:

```
public IPageAdapter OpenNewTab(string url)
{
    var windowHandles = webDriver.WindowHandles;
    scriptExecutor.ExecuteScript(string.Format("window.open('{0}', '_blank');", url));
    var newWindowHandles = webDriver.WindowHandles;
    var openedWindowHandle = newWindowHandles.Except(windowHandles).Single();
    webDriver.SwitchTo().Window(openedWindowHandle);
    return new SeleniumPage(webDriver);
}
```

**Update**

Window open create new popup. By default this option can be blocked by browser settings. Disable popup blocking in your browser manually.

To check this, open js console in your browser and try to execute command window.open('http://facebook.com', '_blank');

If new window open successfully than everythng is OK.

You can also create your chrome driver with specific setting. Here is my code:

```
var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
return new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(150));
```

Comment: This is not working form me.
var webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
                webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
                               
                var windowHandles = webDriver.WindowHandles;
                ((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript(string.Format("window.open('{0}', '_blank');", url));
                var newWindowHandles = webDriver.WindowHandles;                                 
                

                var openedWindowHandle = newWindowHandles.Except(windowHandles).Single();
                webDriver.SwitchTo().Window(openedWindowHandle);

Comment: It throws exception
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
at 
var openedWindowHandle = newWindowHandles.Except(windowHandles).Single();

Comment: actually I'm new to selenium and struggling to understand the code you shared. 
webDriver.WindowHandles returns the action performed on web browser?

Then there is a line to execute javascript. Should this line open up a new tab with that url? I observed no change on browser after executing javascript
can you please tell me what is openedWindowHandle ?
I'm new to it so unable to understand it.

Comment: @sohaibjaved in first line we retieve all opened chrome windows. This collection should contains your current chrome window (or windows if you are opened few chrome tabs before). Then we execute JS that should open our url in new window(_blank).It's a JS trick that shoud works even if we execute this code in url-string in chrome browser. Next we are retrieve open windows again. This collection should contains opened windows and new window that was opened in a previous line. We are except old windows from this collection and switch webDriver to a new window. and return new page with new window.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that my example does not work for you, This is my real code in a production project. I hope that my comments will help you to solve your problem yourself. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your efforts. Please would you tell me why this piece of code is not opening a new tab for me
`using (var driver = new ChromeDriver())
{
     string url = "https://www.facebook.com/";
     IJavaScriptExecutor jscript = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
     jscript.ExecuteScript("window.open('{0}', '_blank');", url);  
}`
and one more thing is it alternative to driver.Navigate().GotoUrl(url) ?
Actually what I need is to open differnt urls (List<string> different tabs) in new tab and then close them after few minutes.

Comment: @sohaibjaved I find an issue. Code window.open('http://facebook.com', '_blank'); opens new popup. Your browser options disable popups. I will update my question to enable this option.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution for open a new tab in seleneium c#:

```
driver.Url = "http://www.gmail.net";
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("window.open();");
```