# Switching tabs not working in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wrote this code in C# and it's not working for me.

Second url is still opening in the first tab, although I switched tabs and updated handle.

```
// open first page in first tab
string firstPageUrl = "http://google.com";
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(firstPageUrl);
// getting handle to first tab
string firstTabHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

// open new tab
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "t").Build().Perform();
string secondTabHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

// open second page in second tab
driver.SwitchTo().Window(secondTabHandle);
string secondPageUrl = "http://bbc.com";
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(secondPageUrl); // FAILED, page is opened in first tab -.-
Thread.Sleep(2000); // slow down a bit to see tab change

// swtich to first tab
action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "1").Build().Perform();
driver.SwitchTo().Window(firstTabHandle);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "2").Build().Perform();
```

I'm using latest Chrome driver.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

This is not duplicate. I am not opening links here, I want to navigate to URL I've provided. Also, I am using `CurrentWindowHandle` as suggested, but it is not working for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open link in new tab selenium c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138838/open-link-in-new-tab-selenium-c-sharp)

Comment: It is not. I am using handles as answer suggested and it's still not working. I have different issue.

Comment: It should be noted that tabs are explicitly unsupported by most WebDriver implementations, and as such, there is no guarantee that the driver would be able to control a new tab opened with the `Control+t` keystroke you're using here. As an aside, I'm not sure I see the use case for doing such a thing, but that's merely an editorial comment, and has no bearing on the actual issue you're facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string secondTabHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;` is still returning the first tab, even if the second tab cover the first one. Try this

```
string firstTabHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "t").Build().Perform();

// switch to the new tab
for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    if (!handle.equals(firstTabHandle))
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    }
}

// close the second tab and switch back to the first tab
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(firstTabHandle);
```

Comment: Your solution has worked but I rewritten it a bit, I'll update my first post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is related to your problem (but I think it might be):

I've found, with selenium, that a better alternative to using `Thread.Sleep()` is using:

`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));`

where first argument is the selenium driver you're using, and the second argument is how long you want to wait before giving up (the timeout)

You can then call:

`wait.Until(condition);`

where `condition` is what you want to wait for. There is a selenium class that provides various useful conditions called `ExpectedConditions`, for example:

`ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By by)`

which would wait for a particular clickable element  to be ready to click.

In fact, I've found that any time the content of the page changes, it's a good idea to wait for the element you're using next like this.

Comment: It has nothing to do with his problem.

Comment: Yeah, fair point actually, the application I'm working on has tabs as part of a page, was tired before lunch and didn't read question properly, he's referring to browser tabs. Still, useful (but entirely unrelated) thing to know about selenium ;)

Comment: I'll remove it if you want, I'm new to Stack Exchange