# Open a new tab in an existing browser session using Selenium

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My current code below in C# opens a window then navigates to the specified URL after a button click.

```
protected void onboardButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body")).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com")
}
```

But the site that I am planning to navigate to has **single sign-on**. How can I open a new tab in my **existing browser session** and navigate from there? The above code does not seem to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34139132/3967709 also has a clearly explained solution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To handle new tab you should switch to it first. Try following:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body")).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com")
```

Also you might need to switch back:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.First());
```

Comment: To clear things up, how should I initialize my driver? Should it be a global variable, right outside my buttonClick method? @Andersson

Comment: `driver` is an instance of your browser session object. If you want to simulate sequence of some actions except your `onboardButton_Click()` you should definitely define `driver` outside this function, globally

Comment: How can I initialize that existing session? I cannot use new ChromeDriver() because it would launch a new window instead of a new tab in the current session.

Comment: You should initialize `driver` just once as global variable and then use it in your code. Sorry I'm not a `C#` coder, so I cannot tell much about how to write `C#` script... check this http://learnseleniumtesting.com/basic-webdriver-and-c-sharp for some tips

Comment: @JPaulPunzalan to make a global driver, make a static class and call it 'SeleniumInfo' or similar and inside it, add a property: "public static IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }" and call it like SeleniumInfo.Driver

Comment: @Andersson @Happy Bird Do you guys have an **idea** on how this could be done in `JavaScript`? Instead of building a **new** window through `chromedriver`, the Selenium script would run on the `existing browser instance instead`. Thanks!

Comment: @JPaulPunzalan, do you mean implementing the same in `JavaScript` + `Selenium` or just the command to pass into `JavaScriptExecutor`?

Comment: @Andersson, Is it possible for the driver to attach to an existing browser instance using `JavaScript` to bypass my firm's `Single Sign-on`?

The workaround that we did before was through a button in a web application which was running on my parent chrome browser that has activated single sign-on. I am currently working on node scripts for browser automation.

Comment: @JPaulPunzalan, it would be better to open new ticket with more details regarding this new issue as for now it's hard for me to understand what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: @Andersson, let's say you have your chrome browser open at this moment (parent browser). Then you ran the selenium JS script via `cmd`.

Right now, I cannot manipulate the chrome browser that is already open (parent browser). Every time I run the Selenium script via cmd, it instead opens a new browser using `chromedriver`.

Comment: @JPaulPunzalan, oh... You mean you want to handle already opened (manually) browser with selenium? If so, AFAIK it's not possible

Comment: How would we open the new Browser

Answer (score 32):

Sending `Keys.Control + "t"` didn't work for me. I had to do it with javascript and then switch to it.

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.open();");
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

Comment: the SendKeys(ctrl T) didn't work for me, but this one did. Plus I could put the URL in the window.open(url), and have it go to the correct page automatically, and not have to do a navigate after opening the tab.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is really simple:

```
Driver.SwitchTo().NewWindow(WindowType.Tab);
```

Enjoy...

Answer (score 2):

This may not works:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body")).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");
```

Alternative: Find clickable element with target blank (search for "blank" in page's surce code). This will open new tab.

Than switch between tabs (thanks @Andersson) with:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.First());
```

Answer (score 2):

We can simulate `Ctrl` + `Element Click`

```
Actions action = new Actions(_driver);
action.KeyDown(Keys.Control).MoveToElement(body).Click().Perform();
```

Reference:
https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/1081051/Open-link-in-New-tab-using-Selenium-Csharp-for-chr#answer3

Answer (score -5):

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Change this to:

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

I do not know why. May be the IWebDriver miss the method.

Comment: How this could solve the issue!? OP need to **switch** to new window to be able to handle it. *IWebDriver miss the method*... Which method?

Comment: You might want to learn more about VAR so you can understand what is happening here :)

Comment: ChromeDriver provides the method "Executescript". IwebDriver doesn't have that method...Please improve the answer..It is not wrong..